# Show results from other page. What is the best method for echoing the results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I used the network developer tool to see if the id is sent to the other page. Which it successfully did. And I can see the other page echo the result but it doesn't show in the modal in the other page even though I have the results.php included in the modal div. Anybody know why this is happening?

itempage.php code:

```
<div id="globalmodal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
         <?php include ("getdata.php");?>
    </div>
</div>
```

results.php code:

```
if (!empty($_POST["data"])) {
   $server = '';
   $dbname = '';
   $dsn = "mysql:host=".$server.";dbname=".$dbname;
   $username = '';
   $password = '';
   $newdata = $_POST["data"];
   $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);   
   $db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `eeee` WHERE `id LIKE '%$newdata%'    GROUP BY `id`");
   $statement->execute();
   $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

   if($row['id']) {
      $pTitle = $row['title'];
      echo '<h4>'.$pTitle.'</h4>';
      echo "Yes it was received!";
   }
}
```

In the itempage.php the getdata.php is included in the div for the modal. But the modal doesn't show the results in the getdata.php page even though the getdata.php has the right title from the database. But the echo doesn't show in the modal pop up.
[image: google network call]

Comment: In itempage a share.php is loaded?

Comment: You don't need to have both isset and empty. `if (!empty($_POST['data'])) { ... }` is enough. `empty()` checks if it exists as well. Another thing... you're not really using prepared statements. You're using unescaped data straight in your query. And yet another thing...  what's the content of share.php? How do you load the results.php?

Comment: What is `share.php`?  We can't really tell you why it's not echoing the value you expect without even knowing what that code *does*.  Also note that it looks like you have a SQL injection vulnerability in `results.php`.

Comment: I thought the prepare statement prevented SQL injection.

Comment: PDO/mysqli_* and prepared statements are not enough to prevent SQL injection, you should use parameterized queries.

Comment: I see what your saying thank you and David

Answer (score 0):

There is a small typographical error in the SQL query:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `eeee` WHERE `id LIKE '%$newdata%'    GROUP BY `id`");
```

It has a missing ``` (it is opened but not closed) for the id used in the `like`. That causes a SQL error, and the condition that displays the result will never be executed (as `$row['id']` will not exist).

As a quick solution, just close it properly like this:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `eeee` WHERE `id` LIKE '%$newdata%'    GROUP BY `id`");
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed it. But I still don't see the echoed statement in my page.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it, I had to leave url for $.ajax blank.